# How to know if I have muxed hardware

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I'm reading [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).

Regarding this statement

> vga_switcheroo is the kernel mechanism that allows you to switch
>   between GPUs if your machine has a hardware mux.

- Does this mean manual or live switching (i.e. automatic)
- How to know if I have hardware mux ? (My machine is **Dell Inspiron SE 7520**)

> Note that this method is not supported by all machines and only works
>   if you are using the opensource driver (nouveau, radeon) and not the
>   proprietary ones (nvidia, fglrx).

- I'm not sure which is which of what I can chose from the **Available Drivers** tab (i.e. please check the the picture below)

[image]

I need to resolve the mentioned questions before proceeding further with the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the specs for your computer, and can't tell if it has a Mux or not.

The arch wiki has a little bit better information about this I think. I found it while looking up what a Mux is.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics

Maybe that will help you decide if you have Mux or not.

In the screen shot it shows that you are using the proprietary AMD driver. To use the vga_switcheroo you have to use the X.org X server (open source, tested) driver.